# prevent strings overflowing in c

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc, overflow

Using C I want to allocate heap space of the maximum initial string length which is 6 in my case and then
    each time the string is about to overflow, double the available space.
I want to build the string char by char.

```
size_t nstring = 6;
char *arr =  malloc(nstring);

int i;
for (i = 0; i < 55;i++){

        if (i == nstring) {
                printf("mAx sized!!");
                arr = realloc(arr, nstring*2);
                nstring = nstring*2;
            }
    arr[i] = 'f';

}
arr[i] = '\0';
printf("length %lu\n", strlen(arr));
free(arr);
```

Comment: And the question is....?

Comment: This code does not work it says invalid next size

Comment: Strlen looks for special character '\0'. You are filling your string with 'f'

Comment: You're using uninitialized memory all the way through. You have no NULL terminator, your strlen goes whack, and you're reallocating without boundaries

Comment: And start with 16 instead of 6. The memory manager (on most systems) is going to round up to a multiple of 16 anyways.

Comment: i disagree about uninitialized memory.  The loop initializes it. And the realloc is not unbounded. We know precisely what it will grow to because the loop only goes to 55 characters. Does need null terminator, but that isn't the main problem.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey - You're right, I didn't notice the `sizeof` issue that you did. That's how we both contribute to the answer. Without the (wrong) sizeof, and had `nstring` been assigned the "correct" size, the allocated size would be 6*(2^[i:1->54]). Regarding uninitialized memory, strlen looks for a NULL terminator which isn't there because it's uninitialized.

Comment: @Amit - you are right. It is uninitialized which results in no null terminator. It doesn't need to be initialized, however, only needs null terminator added after the loop.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey - No, BEFORE the loop, and after every `arr[i] = 'f';` if only a single array item is initialized, since that would run over the previous NULL. Otherwise, strlen won't return the "correct" result.

Comment: @Amit - oh, yes, he is calling strlen over and over. That is pointless, just replace that strlen with i and then no need to initialize.

Comment: Ive edited the code with your recommendations! it runs and compiles, i am not sure if its fail proof though

Comment: Using strlen() at all should gererate a compiler warning: 'W_666: 'Use of strlen() - do you know what it does and how it works?'.

Comment: @FrankduPlessis Instead of editing the question as "solved" and changing the code in the question, please post the solution as an answer to your own question instead and accept that as the correct answer. This will help future readers who have the same problem.

Comment: If the question is solved, just accept whatever answer solves it. You *might* write one yourself if none does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Garr Godfrey and Amit i reached this solution.

```
size_t nstring = 6; 
char *arr =  malloc(nstring);

int i;
for (i = 0; i < 55;i++){

        if (i == nstring) {
                printf("mAx sized!!");
                arr = realloc(arr, nstring*2);
                nstring = nstring*2;
            }
    arr[i] = 'f';

}
arr[i] = '\0';
printf("length %lu\n", strlen(arr));
free(arr);
```

Comment: only potential issue is that you don't check size before adding the null terminator. Can fix by changing check to "if (i+1 == nstring)"

Answer (score 1):

sizeof is the size of the pointer, not the size of the data it points to.

Change

```
nstring = sizeof(arr) + 1;
```

to

```
nstring = nstring*2;
```

Remember, arr is a pointer, and a pointer is always the size of the address (4 for 32bits, 8 for 64bits, etc.).

EDIT:
This is not the only problem. You also need to add the null terminator when you are done, and you also use "sizeof(arr)" in your print statement. You need to fix those as well.

Comment: There is no standard way to determine the size of the memory you allocated. You need to keep track of it yourself, which you already do using nstring. But sizeof does not give you what you want here.

Comment: Ive now edited the code it compiles and runs fine, is it fixed?thanks alot for the help!

Comment: you are actually calling strlen in the loop. I didn't notice before but @amit did. You can just use i instead of strlen, since length will always be the same as i.  If you don't change it, the strlen call in the loop will count beyond the end of the string.